# when to use shared_from_this()

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, enable-shared-from-this

If I want to return a shared_ptr for class A, I should use shared_from_this() feature. But I think this will work after I defined a shared_ptr for A already. So if another place wants a shared_ptr I just use the one I made. I wonder when to use shared_from_this().

sample code:

```
class A : public enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    int a = 0;
    shared_ptr<A> get_this() {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<A> ptr_a(new A);
    cout << ptr_a.use_count() << endl;
    shared_ptr<A> ptr_b = ptr_a->get_this(); 
    // if somewhere else wants a ptr I just use, shared_ptr<A> ptr_b = ptr_a; after pass it 
    // into a function, what situation should i use shared_from_this() for instead ???
    cout << ptr_a.use_count() << endl;
    cout << ptr_b.use_count() << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should use it when you need it and it's convenient. If you don't feel a need to use it, then don't. It's rarely needed.

Comment: I think the question of when to use `shared_from_this` is good, but your understanding is a little bit off. You don't _need_ to use `shared_from_this` just to get a `shared_ptr` if you already have one. `shared_from_this` exists as a mechanism to get the `shared_ptr` of itself from _inside_ the class -- which can be useful for some cases like asynchronous message callbacks. Barring cases like that, you probably won't need to use it at all

Comment: @Human-Compiler Already changed my question to your suggestion. And your answer give me a hint when I see "get the shared_ptr of itself from inside the class". Thx a lot.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is much more frequently / broadly used than is `shared_from_this`. `shared_from_this` is sometimes used in multi-threaded programming with relatively complex designs. For reference, see [this](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1414193955/enable_shared_from_this-overview-examples-and-internals) post on enable_shared_from_this - overview, examples, and internals.

Comment: @aafulei  Very useful information and link in your reply, very appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have a misunderstanding about `shared_ptr` and `shared_from_this`.

You don't *need* to use `shared_from_this` in order to retrieve a `shared_ptr` if you already have one. In your example, you could just do:

```cpp
auto ptr_a = std::make_shared<A>();
auto ptr_b = ptr_a;
```

However, there are cases where a design requires that a class be aware of its shared lifetime -- and must be able to retrieve a `shared_ptr` to itself. In such a case, you can't simply do: `std::shared_ptr<A>{ this }` because this would be producing a *new* `shared_ptr` node that is tracking the pointer of `this` -- which could result in a bad/double deletion.

`shared_from_this()` solves this by allowing the internals of the class to be able to retrieve safe `shared_ptr` object to the object that was allocated. In my experience, this pattern is most common with asynchronous callback handlers. For example:

```cpp
auto A::do_something_async() -> void
{
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    std::thread{[self]{
        // do something long-living with 'self'
    }}.detach();
}
```

**Note:** I am not advocating for this style of code; just that this is a possible use for it. In general I find it better to design classes such that it never relies on knowing its own lifetime.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code means if I want to do some async work, I need to guarantee my class is still alive and it is more safe to use shared ptr inside the class. Right?

Comment: Yep, you would need to guarantee that the object being acted on is alive. `shared_from_this` is just a tool to achieve that for the case where you want the instance to be aware of its own shared lifetime. There are, of course, other ways to achieve this without using `shared_from_this` -- such as sharing only the _data_ and not having the entirety of the class be aware of the shared lifetime.

Comment: I recommend for class with `std::enable_shared_from_this<A>` to make constructors private and provide factory methods which return a `std::shared_ptr`. So no possible misuses of `shared_from_this()` from object not handled by `std::shared_ptr`.